# How to use/install certain library in Android Studio

Tags: android

I found this "amazing" library that i think it would look nice in my small project but i don't find how to use it / how to install.
This is the url:
https://github.com/kmshack/Android-ParallaxHeaderViewPager

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be available via Maven (see [here](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/536)). It might be an old version however. You could also import the project into Android Studio, build the jar and put it in your project's libs folder. A third option would be to make it build as part of your own project. For the latter you can use [this](https://github.com/klinker41/android-chips) for inspiration.